# Tracking the use of Ctrl + F by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, analytics

Is it possible to know what my users are searching for on my web pages by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in JavaScript? So when a user uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search for something, JavaScript can capture this action (and the search phrase) and send it back to the server.

Possible? How?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: I don't know how. I searched in Google it's all triggering Ctrl + F key rather than to track it.

Comment: found via google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93695/best-cross-browser-method-to-capture-ctrls-with-jquery (replace S keycode with F). This can track the keystroke - tracking what they type in the search box is out of javascripts ability.

Comment: Sorry, I can only go so far as getting the ctrl+f key strokes.  Retrieving the text they are searching for in the browser is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not possible. On *some* browsers you can catch the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, but you can't spy on what the user searched for. On other browsers you can't catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> at all.

If it's any consolation, there's probably a security flaw you can use on IE6.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't and by all security reasons should never have access to browser's UI elements outside page. You can capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and handle it on your own though. But, of course, it will look different than browser's own UI element.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found a workaround that might help in some cases.

Notice, that document and scrollable elements are always scrolling to the next searched occurrence - we can take advantage of that and create an "hidden" scrollable element and wait for it to scroll.
When it scrolls you can then read the position to which it scrolled and get matched word.

http://jsfiddle.net/oz6gum90/6/

HTML:

```
<div id="hiddenScrollableContent">
    <div></div> <!-- first element must be empty -->
    <div>car</div>
    <div>cat</div>
    ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#hiddenScrollableContent{
    overflow: scroll;
    position:absolute;
    height:20px;  /* can't be zero ! */
    opacity:0.01; /* can't be zero ! */
    pointer-events: none;
}
#hiddenScrollableContent div{
    height: 100px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#hiddenScrollableContent').scroll(function(e){
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (top==0)
        return; //prevents endless loop

    var index = Math.round(top / 100);
    var element = $('div', this).eq(index);
    var elementsText = element.text();
    $(this).scrollTop(0);

    console.log('top:'+top, 'index:'+index);

    $('span').text(elementsText);
});
```