# Capture CTRL+S cross-browser with ExtJS 4.x and avoid browser action

Tags: extjs, cross-browser, extjs4, dom-events, extjs4.1

I want to stop default browser action <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and have my RIA save the form data while user press this key combination for our application.

We are using ExtJS 4.1.x

Similar solution here using jQuery:
[Best cross-browser method to capture CTRL+S with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93695/best-cross-browser-method-to-capture-ctrls-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I usually do it in ExtJS apps (last case statement below), it seems to work well for me:

```
// attach key navigation to document
Ext.getDoc().on('keypress', function(event, target) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && !event.shiftKey) {
        event.stopEvent();

        switch(event.getKey()) {

            case event.LEFT :
                this.shiftTabs(-1);
                break;

            case event.RIGHT :
                this.shiftTabs(1);
                break;

            case event.DELETE :
                this.closeActiveTab();
                break;

            case event.F4 : // this is actually the "S" key
                this.saveAll(); // handler
                break;

            // other cases...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not cross browser compatible.  You need to listen to the `keydown` event instead of `keypress`.  Also, when listening to `keydown`, you don't need to listen to `event.F4`, it will be `event.S` as you would expect.