# Is ASCII 19 used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, ascii

I used a SO answer in my page for [saving text on Ctrl+S](https://stackoverflow.com/q/93695/938236), but as I don't like just copy-pasting without understanding first, I decided to do so first. It's a simple jQuery script, which I converted (still working) to this:

```
/* A key is pressed */
$(window).keypress(function(event) {
  /* Ctrl + S or ?? */
  if ((event.which == 115 && event.ctrlKey) || (event.which == 19)) {
    savedata();
    event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

The bit I'm asking about is **`event.which == 19`**. A [quick search on ASCII codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart) tells me it's "Device Control 3 (oft. XOFF)". However, [the link of XOFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOFF) and google didn't bring much light to the subject. So,

**Is the ASCII character 19 (Device Control 3) still used in some computers/keyboards/other devices or can I securely delete that bit?**

Note: I want to delete it so I can change it to a switch and I don't have any hanging, not understood code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIR `which` is key scancode, not an ASCII code.
Anyway, code 19 should stand for some key like arrow or somewhat, which doesn't have printable representation like letter or digit. E.g. `[Esc]` has code 27.

http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes - looks correct.

Comment: Thanks, I visited that link but it wasn't until I looked down to the keyboard and saw "Pause Break" that I realized I have that key. However, it's not desirable that it saves the document when you press "Pause Break", I will change it accordingly. I'll wait to accept this just in case someone has more information (like, maybe that key is mapped to "save" in some keyboards).

Comment: Ther're also media keys, like play/pause/etc. most of them have standard codes as well.