# Not able to use Ctrl+A in textbox

Tags: asp.net

When i use below javascript which disables all alphabets, so not able to use Ctrl+A .. help is appriciated

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function validate(key) {
      var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode;
     var phn = document.getElementById('Textbox6');
     if (!(keycode == 8 || keycode == 46) && (keycode < 48 || keycode > 57)) {
         return false;
     }
     else {
       if (phn.value.length < 10) {
             return true;
         }
         else {
             return false;
         }
     }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best cross-browser method to capture CTRL+S with JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93695/best-cross-browser-method-to-capture-ctrls-with-jquery) - That shuold give you a clue to adjust your if statement

Answer (score 0):

See here [How to detect Ctrl+V, Ctrl+C using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript)

you will found how to detect ctrl+a key and then when user press that one you wrtie return true

i hope this will help you give me feedback is that working? regards...:)

remember

> 65

is key a's code

**[UPDATE]**

```
function validate(key) {
     var ctrlDown = false;
     aKey = 86;
       var ctrlKey = 17;
      var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode;
     var phn = document.getElementById('Textbox6');
      if (keyCode == ctrlKey)
      {
       ctrlDown = true;
       }
       if(ctrlKey && (keycode==aKey))
       {
        return true;
       }
     if (!(keycode == 8 || keycode == 46) && (keycode < 48 || keycode > 57)) {
         return false;
     }
     else {
       if (phn.value.length < 10) {
             return true;
         }
         else {
             return false;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I want only ctrl+A and disable all alphabets...will you alter my above code with that

Comment: What is the problem check in console

Comment: What will you allow if you disable alphabets?

Comment: disable all alphabets and works only ctrl+a with numbers ... but your modified code is allowing all alphabets