# is it possible to bind ctrl+s on click event in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a code to bind the save as option on click event.I don't want to use filesaver.js. I want pure javascript to write this code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93695/best-cross-browser-method-to-capture-ctrls-with-jquery

Comment: yes, it is possible and lots of apps do it... unfortunately they don't support command+s for mac users :P

Comment: @Vivek As far as I can tell this question is asking the opposite of the ones you linked - not how to capture ctrl+s keyboard events, but to trigger ctrl+s/save-as commands by methods _other_ than keyboard/app-menu methods

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 standards introduced the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/), which should allow scripts to offer up "files" (Blobs) for users to save. Support is shoddy, though, which is why polyfills like [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) exist. Filesaver.js is "pure" javascript, too, so I'm not sure why needing a pure javascript solution precludes its use (unless you mean you can't load outside scripts - just minify and inline it (along with licence, etc.)) Right now, if you must code it yourself, any cross-browser solution you come up with is likely to be an effective rewrite of the polyfil.

Once you have an implementation of `saveAs()`, simply attach it to whatever event trigger you like:

```
myButton.addEventListener( 'click', function() { window.saveAs( fileBlob, 'filename.txt' ) } );
```

**Clarification:** As per the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#trusted-events) on Events, all untrusted events (includes key-press events) act as if `event.preventDefault()` was called - so there is *explicitly* no way to simulate an actual <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> keypress - only ways to simulate its effects.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var isCtrlPressed = false;

function onKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 17) { // Control got pressed
        isCtrlPressed = true;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 83) { // "s" got pressed
        // if control is pressed too execute some code
        if (isCtrlPressed) {
            // Your code here
        }
    }
}

function onKeyUp(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 17) { // Control got pressed
        isCtrlPressed = false;
    }
}
```

Then on your body tag add the following events:

```
<body onkeydown="onKeyDown(event)" onkeyup="onKeyUp(event)">
</body>
```

You can find a lifedemo here:
http://jsbin.com/eBIRAfA/1/edit

Comment: I think this is the wrong way around. On a mouse event, these key events should be emitted and not the other way around.