# Using "CTRL + S " Keys to execute a pl/sql code in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I have an editable interactive reports in Oracle APEX 5.0, having 5-6 APEX_ITEMS and I have a update button on clicking which a pl/sql code is fired to save the edited changes in the db.

My requirement is to be able to the run the same pl/sql code(which executes on Pressing the update button) when <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> keys are pressed on the keyboard.

I tried using KEY DOWN and KEY RELEASE Dynamic actions and java script but nothing worked.

Please do respond with the solution as this is a critical requirement!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best cross-browser method to capture CTRL+S with JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93695/best-cross-browser-method-to-capture-ctrls-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do so with custom javascript and then can you recall yours plsql.
I hope this help [ctrl+s jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93695/best-cross-browser-method-to-capture-ctrls-with-jquery)