# how to capture CTRL+S in browser

Tags: javascript, events

I have a page on which I want to override default <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> behavior. When typing this on google or stack-overflow, I can only find ways to do it [with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/93695/6320039):

```
$(window).keypress(function(event) {
    if (!(event.which == 115 && event.ctrlKey) && !(event.which == 19)) return true;
    alert("Ctrl-S pressed");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

I'd like to have a clean way to do it with **vanilla JS**.

Comment: @jimmyweb I saw this question already (it is even quoted in mine). But I want **vanilla js**

Comment: @jimmyweb this is not a duplicate of that question. OP wants **non-jquery** solutions, your dupe doesn't answer that.

Comment: Just answered below.

Comment: @MountainKing Thanks, somehow I struggled to find it.

Comment: FYI: Doesn't work on Chrome in year 2022.  Not exactly sure why but I see event.which is now considered "non-standard":  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a big difference from the jQuery implementation:

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (!(event.which == 115 && event.ctrlKey) && !(event.which == 19)) return true
  alert("Ctrl-S pressed")
  event.preventDefault()
  return false
})
```