# Triggering Ctrl S via button in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna use my browser's save as function. How can i trigger `CTRL`+`S` via button in javascript. Is it possible ?
i have tried this

```
$("#Save").click(function() {
    var e = $.Event( "keydown", { keyCode: 115, ctrlKey:true} );
    $("body").trigger(e);
});
```

Comment: This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/93836/11719787)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best cross-browser method to capture CTRL+S with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93695/best-cross-browser-method-to-capture-ctrls-with-jquery)

Comment: @sjv is not asking how to determine if `Ctrl + S` has been pressed, but asking if it is possible to Trigger it.

Comment: If you want to trigger the "Save As" dialog by custom events then it is not allowed due to security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a custom event using `KeyboardEvent`. But default action associated with the event (e.g. `ctrl+s`, `ctrl+p`) is not initiated by the browser. Take a look at following note from MDN

> Source - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent
>
> Note:  Manually firing an event does not generate the default action
>   associated with that event. For example, manually firing a key event
>   does not cause that letter to appear in a focused text input. In the
>   case of UI events, this is important for security reasons, as it
>   prevents scripts from simulating user actions that interact with the
>   browser itself.

Code to fire custom event:

```js
(() => {
  document.querySelector("#saveMe").addEventListener('click', ($event) => {

    let event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
      key: "s",
      code: "KeyS",
      ctrlKey: true
    });

    document.dispatchEvent(event);
  });

  document.addEventListener('keydown', ($event) => {
    console.log('keydown fired', $event);
  });

})();
```

```html
<input type="button" id="saveMe" value="Save Me">
```

Answer (score 0):

Only with jQuery, Import it to your File.

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey && (e.which == 83)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Ctrl+S');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: I dont want to capture this keys. I wanna see Browser's "Save As" pop-up when button is clicked.

Comment: Take return false; out of the code and put your message in alert('your message');

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

You can simulate `ctrl`+`s` on `click` event like below example:

```
$("#Save").click(function() {
  e = $.Event("keydown");
  e.which = 83; // S
  e.ctrlKey = true; // CTRL
  $(document).trigger(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as far as I can tell. For security reasons, it would not be sensible for browsers to allow Javascript to trigger events that interact with the browser like that.

However there is an experimental [FileSystemAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) you could use.

You could create your own modal-popup, and use the FileSystemAPI to read local files, and prompt the user to select a save location.